# More than one typeahead on the page, each one with a different template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I know that it is possible to customize the templates of the ui.bootstrap.typeahead either by:

- declaring the 'typeahead-template-url' (for the internal 'typeahead-match.html' file) and/or
- using $templateCache to customize the outer template ('typeahead-popup.html').

My issue is that I want to have two typeaheads on the same page, but with different templates, both internal(typeahead-match.html) and external (typeahead-popup.html), is it possible?

Comment: yes it's possible..any issues?

Comment: @Asik, I don't know how. Imagine that I have two typeahead on the same page and the outer template(typeahead-popup.html) needs to be different for each one, how do i do it since $templateCache will hold the same id('template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html') for both directives.

Comment: Check the typeahead demo, they used different sample in single page http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Yes, but they all use the same template. Maybe I could reformulate my question. I want to have two typeaheads on the same page, but with different templates, both internal(typeahead-match.html) and external (typeahead-popup.html), is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the angular-ui-bootstrap FAQ:

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ

The first item there is about the templates... most importantly if you use one of the files with `-tpls-` in the name, the templates are in-lined (added to the template cache as part of the JS file using HTML strings, thus no longer needing the html files).